# Java socket file upload to server, server not taking the first bytes of byte array

Tags: java, sockets

I am writing a socket program in java which is supposed to upload a file from client by breaking it into chunks of 512 bytes. But apparently the server is not writing the first 512 bytes into file.
My client code

```
DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
dOut.writeUTF(number);
dOut.flush(); // Send off the data

File myFile = new File(name);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[512];

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);
dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);

OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();

//Sending file name and file size to the server
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(ostream);
dos.writeUTF(myFile.getName());
dos.writeLong(mybytearray.length);
int count;
while ((count = dis.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
    dos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
}
dos.close();
dis.close();
```

My server code

```
DataInputStream dIn = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String number = dIn.readUTF();
File path = new File(Globals.rootPath+"/"+number);
if(!path.exists())  path.mkdir();

DataInputStream clientData = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
String name = clientData.readUTF();
File outfile = new File(Globals.rootPath+"/"+number+"/"+name);

OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

long size = clientData.readLong();
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int count;
while ((count = dIn.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    output.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
output.close();
dIn.close();
```

I know the code is extremely messy and there are a lot of unnecessary things. This is the first time I am using socket and I will clean this up after I get this to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are calling `dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length)`, but not using the value, so the first 512 bytes are discarded.

Next, you are writing file name (`writeUTF(...)`) and array length (`writeLong(...)`), before the data, but you are only reading the file name (`readUTF()`), not the array length, so the 8 bytes of array length becomes the first 8 bytes of data.

FYI: Chunk size is relatively meaningless, in that client and server don't have to use same block size. It's all a stream of data in the socket, and the socket implementation may buffer and chop the stream data into pieces that better fit the transmission protocol (likely Ethernet).

Comment: Chunk size might be meaningless, but it is a requirement of this networking offline assignment. Will removing `dis.readFully(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length)` from code solve the problem?